# Is there any way in Quarkus to control the @incomming message from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I'm new to quarkus, I would like to listen to a kafka topic but only in some environments.

```
   @Incoming("my-topic")
    public void consumeCreation(Record<String, MyClass> record) {
        MyClass teste = record.value();
         
        (more code...)
    }
```

I will use this topic to do some mocking, and I don't want to listen to it in the production environment.
Is there any way to not run the @Incoming based on a variable?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Incoming` method must be in a class which is a CDI bean. You can annotate that class with `@UnlessBuildProfile("prod")`, which means that the bean will be ignored in the `prod` profile.

This should let you control when will the `@Incoming` method be used. (If not, that would be a bug.)

There's a couple more annotations that let you do similar things:

- `@IfBuildProfile`
- `@IfBuildProperty`
- `@UnlessBuildProperty`

Comment: Thanks for the help